# In select2,why should I have to put the $('select').val(); to the click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

You know ,I just learning  about select2.I need to get the value of the selected option,I know I should do like this:

```
$('select').val();
```

So I just write a simple problem like this :

HTML:

```
<button id="clickIt">click</button>

<p>SELECT NUMBER</p>
<select id='first'>
<option value='1'>First</option>
<option value='2'>Second</option>
<option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
<p id="set1"></p>
```

I have also add Jquery  and select2 library.

when I write JS ,I found this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#first").select2();
//var a=$("#first").val(); // it always alert 1,so a always equals 1.
$('#clickIt').on("click",function(){

var a=$('#first').val(); // that is the resule what I want .
alert(a);

})

})
```

I want to know why   var a=$('#first').val();  put another position will have another effect?

Answer (score 0):

Because  `$("#first").val();` returns the **currently** selected value not the **future** one. So, when you call `$("#first").select2();` and you try to retrieve the value you will get the **currently** selected value.

But when you call `$("#first").val();` inside the click event, each time you click `#clickIt` then `$("#first").val();` will be called and return the newly selected value.

I hope this will make sense to you.